# Can I use feature selection methods on PCA columns in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have been working on a dataset whose columns are PCA values of the original features, in R. Can I use other feature selection methods like boruta / random Forest on PCA columns to further reduce the feature space by considering only the more important features?

Answer (score 0):

PCA is data transformation procedure for reducing dimensions and not for deciding which features are important. It transforms the feature space in such a way that maximum possible variance is concentrated in the first PCA component and then in second and so on. There is a way to decide how many PCA components are to be considered. We select as many PCA components as have within themselves 95% of total variance. Thus, PCA procedure itself contains the selection process of PCA components. 
However, if number of features are very large, one may use Boruta first to decide important features and then apply PCA on them to further reduce number of dimensions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.

The original features of my dataset are not shown due to security issues. The columns I have with me are the PCA reduced features of original dataset. I would like to know wether I can apply any feature selection method on PCA columns to further reduce my feature space?